# Minimal working example for RViz marker publishing

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, python3, rospy, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know of a complete minimal working example to publish a marker that can be visualised in `RViz` written in `Python`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373802/minimal-working-example-for-rviz-marker-publishing/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-03-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a minimal working example of a ROS node in Python with a Rviz marker publisher:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker

rospy.init_node('rviz_marker')

marker_pub = rospy.Publisher("/visualization_marker", Marker, queue_size = 2)

marker = Marker()

marker.header.frame_id = "/map"
marker.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

# set shape, Arrow: 0; Cube: 1 ; Sphere: 2 ; Cylinder: 3
marker.type = 2
marker.id = 0

# Set the scale of the marker
marker.scale.x = 1.0
marker.scale.y = 1.0
marker.scale.z = 1.0

# Set the color
marker.color.r = 0.0
marker.color.g = 1.0
marker.color.b = 0.0
marker.color.a = 1.0

# Set the pose of the marker
marker.pose.position.x = 0
marker.pose.position.y = 0
marker.pose.position.z = 0
marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
  marker_pub.publish(marker)
  rospy.rostime.wallsleep(1.0)
```

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2021-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-03-15**:
That's really great, just what I needed! My next task is to colour code each marker according to a sensor value like a heat map. Any ideas how I'd achieve this?

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2021-03-15**:
I am glad that this resolved your question. To change to color of one marker use the attribute .color , it is shown above. For a heatmap  it seems to me that you need many markers. Take a look at visualization_msgs/MarkerArray message.  It is a bit broad subject to discuss here in details.

**Comment by [jstm](https://answers.ros.org/users/35977/jstm/) on 2022-12-06**:
For future readers: This wasn't working for me, I was getting the error `For frame [/map]: Frame [/map] does not exist`. After spending probably way too long on this, I realized that `/map` indeed does not exist in the tf tree (run `rosrun tf view_frames` to get a pdf of the tree) - but `map` IS in the tree. I changed the `frame_id` to `map` and then it worked.

TLRD: If your getting  `For frame [/map]: Frame [/map] does not exist` try changing `marker.header.frame_id = "/map"` to `marker.header.frame_id = "map"`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @py,

Just take a look at the [link below](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DavidB-CMU/rviz_tools_py/master/src/rviz_tools_py/rviz_tools.py) might be you can get help from [this python code](https://adioshun.gitbooks.io/ros_autoware/content/Tools/Rviz/rviz-tools-for-python.html).

You can publish transformation(tf2) of each markers by `sendTransform()` function.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-03-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2